# Finding sum of Stirling numbers (signed) of the first kind $\sum_{k=0}^n s(n,k)$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs, stirling-numbers

> Compute $\sum_{k=0}^n s(n,k)=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k}{n\brack k}$.

From definition, it's clear than the sum of the unsigned Stirling numbers is: $$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\brack k}=n!$$

But I'm stucked at $\sum_{k=0}^n s(n,k)$, since definition of the signed version is given by a falling factorial. Any hint?

Comment: You say the "definition of the signed version is given by a falling factorial," can you write out this definition in your post? Once you write out this definition, it takes a single trick to evaluate $\sum_{k=0}^n s(n,k)$.

Comment: Look
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Definitions

Comment: Choose a particular value for $x$, and substitute it into that equation, and the identity you want falls out.